# Issue in create-react-app : The term 'create-react-app' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I have Node(v6.10.3) and npm(3.10.10) installed on my system. I installed `create-react-app` on it and it was successful. However, when i try to create a new project on my machine by simply running: `create-react-app sample-app`, it gives me following error:

> create-react-app : The term 'create-react-app' is not recognized as
>   the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
>   the path is correct and try again. 
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + create-react-app
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (create-react-app:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Have been working with the cli for years and never encountered this. Someone got any idea why this could be happening? Is it related to version of npm/node?

Comment: this problem related to the new version of cra 2.* I personaly was not able to use it before updated to node 10. now we have to use npx create-react-app wich is going with node 10+

Comment: Use this instead:
```
npm init react-app name
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should install `create-react-app` globally with `-g`.

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Alternatively, you could skip the installation of `create-react-app`.
For that you need firstly to update to a newer version of nodejs and npm and then you can run.

```
npx create-react-app yourappname
```

Comment: Then please also update your Nodejs. You seem to run a old version, check with `node --version` and `npm --version`

Answer (score 0):

You should install first node [Download Here.](https://nodejs.org/en/)
Then see node version in command prompt : `node -v` & `npx -v`
Finally create react app `npx create-react-app app-name`
`cd app-name`
`npm start`

Comment: ```appName``` never contains capital letter, change to ```app-name```

Answer (score 0):

I used cmd `npx create-react-app app-name` instead of `create-react-app app-name`.
It works successfully. but I don't know how it was solved.